# How to serve http web application request through Bastion Host?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-bastion

I have created Bastion Host and one Virtual machine(with out public IP) in Azure, I am able to login to my VM through Bastion Host, Now i want to deploy flask application in VM than i have to allow flask web application requests to VM through Bastion Host.

How can i access my flask application urls through bastion host?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure's bastion host per se. But if there aren't any unusual restrictions, you should be able to use SSH tunneling. https://serverfault.com/questions/78351/can-i-create-ssh-to-tunnel-http-through-server-like-it-was-proxy

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Bastion, you can secure and seamless RDP and SSH access to your virtual machines over SSL from the Azure portal and without exposing public IP addresses. You just need to prepare your application as usual then you can SSH access to your VM and access the application from the Azure portal with the localhost address. It looks like that you can access the application within a VNet.

For example, I have a windows VM without public Ip but enable IIS and there is a static website. I can access the website with URL `http://localhost/` or `http://<privateIpaddressofVM>`.

[image]

> Azure Bastion uses an HTML5 based web client that is automatically
> streamed to your local device so that you get your RDP/SSH session
> over TLS on port 443 enabling you to traverse corporate firewalls
> securely.

Read [Azure Bastion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-overview) for more details.